# gluing bundles as a 2-colimit

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, dg.differential-geometry

Is the gluing of bundles from not-necessarily trivial bundles just some kind of 2-colimit?

Comment: Gluing is an ordinary colimit, so you can certainly think of it as "some kind of 2-colimit", if you really believe that helps you.

Comment: Johannes is right. What you might be thinking is, the category of principal  bundles over a fixed base is a $2$-colimit over all covers of the base (or some cofinal subset) of the categories of principal bundles over that fixed base which trivialize over the given cover.

Comment: @Carchedi: I wasn't actually ;), but after Johannes comment I realised he was right but I still felt there was a 2-colimit involved somewhere but was struggling to make the statement clear. Thanks for clarifying. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not my answer, but David Carchedi's answer in a comment:

'What you might be thinking is, the category of principal bundles over a fixed base is a 2-colimit over all covers of the base (or some cofinal subset) of the categories of principal bundles over that fixed base which trivialize over the given cover'